# PHP Mysqli bind_result throws warning during prepared insert statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The below prepared statement has 5 variables.

`INSERT INTO folder (folder_name, folder_parent_id, folder_user_id, folder_order, hk_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);`

I'm getting this warning when I call `$_STATEMENT->bind_result( $_RESULT );`

`Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

While obviously this is true ( 5 variables, 1 result variable ) an INSERT statement when executed only returns true (success) or false (failure).  Just in case there were something I were missing, I tried providing 5 variables to `bind_result()` and I still got the same message.

The Insert query executes successfully.  Should I just @suppress the warning and chalk this up as either a quirk or bug in PHP (sometimes I wonder if there is a difference) or is there something I'm missing?

**Edited to reflect that I tried giving 5 variables to bind_result()**

Comment: `an INSERT statement when executed only returns true or false`.  Yes.  There is no result to bind to.  INSERT doesn't have a "result".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) with an `INSERT` query.  It doesn't have a result.

[`$_STATEMENT->execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Use [`$_STATEMENT->affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) if you want to see how many rows were inserted.

Comment: That makes so much more sense now, thanks! I thought I would need to bind to get the true false but I guess that would be the same true/false given by execute()

Comment: Yeah, `bind_result` is for the fields returned from the query.  Only `SELECT`s have a "result" :-P